# Cursor flickering and disappearing with dual-screen setup

Tags: 15.04, cursor, nouveau, flicker

I've recently installed Ubuntu 15.04 under unity and set up a dual screen.

For the two screens I'm using my GTX 760 using Nouveau drivers (I couldn't use nvidia's because they were not working, but that is another problem).
The first one is directly plugged with HDMI to my gtx.
But because the second one is VGA-only, I did plug it into my motherboard. It works well, since the gtx is properly rendering to this screen through intel's gpu.

There is no issue with this, but I've got a problem on my first screen : The cursor keeps flickering and sometimes diseappearing. In display settings I'm only seeing my main screen and my second screen, not any other "Unknown display", so there's nothing to remove there. I didn't find any other solution yet. When I'm disabling the second screen, my cursor no more flickers. I'm not having this issue on Windows 7.

Edit : Another detail. If I'm putting my cursor in-between my two screens, the half is flickering, and the other is not.

Any idea? (PS : I am kinda a newbie to linux, so if you could give clear/detailed answers, it would be even better). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try enter this in the terminal it might work:

```
gsettings set org.settings.gnome-cursor active=false
```

only idea I have, and it might work fine this way.

Comment: It throws me out that the syntax is not correct. Utilisation :
  gsettings [--schemadir RÉPERTOIRE2SCHÉMA] set SCHÉMA[:CHEMIN] CLÉ VALEUR. It's in french, in english I'd say it's that : gsettings [--schemadir SCHEMAFOLDER] set SCHEMA[:PATH] KEY VALUE. Are you sure the syntax is correct..?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the setting @Michael; not sure if it helps though, YMMV.

`gsettings list-schemas` helps as it lists the available schema.

`gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active` reports the current value,

`gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active false` changes it.

For me there seems little change, the mouse cursor is only available reliably on the top couple of lines of the screen.